# Can an empty session ID drop a TLS connection?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soapui

I am not familiar with networking protocols.  I am trying to find out why a java/axis web service client is failing at the following:

```
org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket
```

The same web service when called using SoapUI is successful.  I have web service client code with debug enabled.  It would seem like the server is resetting the connection (connection reset by peer).

I installed Fiddler to capture the output.When I call the web service through the client and through SoapUI, I see in Fiddler output that Session ID is empty  in case of the client but is populated in case of SoapUI.

Is there a significance?

We are using TLS 1.2

I have a bit of the debug trace:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 194, 161, 226, 146, 53, 227, 73, 65, 160, 25, 176, 19, 190, 44, 242, 231, 224, 236, 65, 80, 185, 185, 188, 231, 158, 187, 210, 142, 5, 179, 166, 199, 61, 210, 152, 235, 159, 85, 223, 64, 65, 46, 145, 37, 20, 161, 37, 167, 248, 28, 22, 136, 126, 111, 59, 75, 171, 211, 155, 173, 128, 231, 157, 46 }
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 70
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: C3 43 D3 ED 59 87 1E 50   D3 41 00 20 2B D0 4E 82  .C..Y..P.A. +.N.
0010: 93 A3 23 3A C3 A2 AA 25   57 05 87 E9 4F AD BE D0  ..#:...%W...O...
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 58 9A 19 A1 72 F6 42 0A   80 11 48 6D 5F 41 1A DB  X...r.B...Hm_A..
0010: 9A F3 3D 19 9C C9 DB A1   61 83 B8 F6 1C 95 56 FF  ..=.....a.....V.
Server Nonce:
0000: 00 00 00 AC F8 6A 39 EC   74 6E 1A E1 60 A3 04 41  .....j9.tn..`..A
0010: 85 DD 0E 93 30 3C A1 72   C8 72 22 3C 78 4B CA B4  ....0<.r.r"<xK..
Master Secret:
0000: 7F DF 53 FE 94 83 06 1A   BF 5D 25 C4 68 A5 75 E0  ..S......]%.h.u.
0010: 0F B0 E4 A2 62 16 72 10   6D 9C BA EC F5 FE 99 B6  ....b.r.m.......
0020: 14 5A 9F C9 08 1F 80 CD   89 7C BF 10 E8 65 7A F9  .Z...........ez.
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: A0 58 73 08 70 8B 7F B7   61 D3 71 7C 42 84 92 43  .Xs.p...a.q.B..C
0010: 63 92 41 28                                        c.A(
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 09 82 39 7C BB 2F 87 7D   F2 C5 6C B0 C5 C2 DE 15  ..9../....l.....
0010: 56 13 3B 84                                        V.;.
Client write key:
0000: 0E 41 5F 0B 75 5B 57 BA   F1 E5 6D E2 9A 5C 0F 6E  .A_.u[W...m..\.n
0010: 25 C2 D1 A5 47 CB E4 13                            %...G...
Server write key:
0000: BD 14 7A 84 8B C9 B6 F0   34 47 D9 16 26 A8 C8 10  ..z.....4G..&...
0010: EC 0F C0 16 6F F2 BF AE                            ....o...
... no IV derived for this protocol
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 8, 158, 120, 64, 191, 49, 98, 178, 64, 33, 81, 158 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 48
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 48
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 197, 21, 32, 254, 164, 129, 235, 95, 24, 109, 84, 233 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
main, setSoTimeout(600000) called
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 752
main, received EOFException: ignored
main, called closeInternal(false)
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 32
main, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
org.apache.axis.AxisFault
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (0)null
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail:
```

Comment: No, that's not significant. If the client never successfully connected then it cannot have a TLS session to resume.

Comment: Are you saying that the connection never happened?  I see a server hello in the trace.  I have added a bit of the trace.

Comment: With the new information added it looks like that the handshake was successfully established and the client wrote application data to the server, then the server closed. This looks like the problem is not at the TLS level but the server did not like the application data sent by your client (after the handshake) and thus closed the connection. I suggest that your client is sending a different HTTP/SOAP request than the SoapUI and the server does not like it.